# Getting _corrupt_record when loading json response to spark dataframe in databricks

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I've been trying to get data from https://anapioficeandfire.com/ and load it to spark dataframe.
Everything works fine until I reach character #1173 and I get _corruptedrecord error

> (AnalysisException: Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV
> files are disallowed when the referenced columns only include the
> internal corrupt record column)

I think it has something to do with an escape character in *alias* column although I have no idea how to resolve it.

Part of my code is below. This should be enough to get to the error. Maybe someone has already resolved this?

```
import json
import requests

def send_request(api_object):
  
  page = 1173
  url = 'https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/'
  
  req = url + api_object + '?page=' + str(page)+ '&pageSize=1'
  response = requests.get(req)
  results = response.json()
  
  return results 

dbutils.fs.put("books.json",  str(send_request('characters')), True) 
df = spark.read.json("books.json", multiLine=True)
#df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([send_request('characters')]))
display(df)

send_request('characters')
```